# Formulating MCTS with random outcomes of actions?

Tags: monte-carlo-tree-search

I am working on implementing MCTS for a scheduling problem where MCTS is formulated each time there are multiple jobs that need to be scheduled. When a job is executed, the resulting state of the system is random. The challenge I'm having is that the implementation I'm currently using relies on the ability to determine if a node is fully expanded. However, there are so many children of the root node that it's not feasible to expect all of them will ever be visited. Is there a suggested method of conducting MCTS in cases where nodes will not likely ever be fully expanded?

Comment: Welcome to AI.SE @hoffee. I think you're asking how to perform MCTS when actions have non-deterministic outcomes. Is that the essence of your question, or are you trying to ask something else?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm asking.

Comment: There is a great paper "A Survey of Monte Carlo Tree Search Methods". Read the chapter on stochastic MCTS. Short: introduce "random nodes" - fake player which do random actions.

Comment: I am aware of that paper but I will revisit that chapter, thanks for the suggestion.